# PrimeNG Table Flex Size

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular6, primeng

I am trying to figure out how to get the PrimeNG's table component fit and scale within a container and application using flex layouts.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ue4ycr)

I can't seem to figure out how to get the grid to stay at the min height and grow as needed till the max height is met. The table itself should grow up to this size, and once there are more records then this, it should scroll.

The footer should be placed at the last record, but instead it shows the white space of the container which results in this wasted space that can be consolidated.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: your demo is not opening..can you paste your grid code here??

Comment: @DirtyMind I've edited to now have the correct link in the question to the stack blitz.